# Large Regression dataset

Tags: regression, data-analysis

For a project I need a large regression (least squares) dataset:

If $n$ is the number of samples and $p$ the number of features, then I need $p < n$ and
$p,n$ both very large. For example $n=10,000,000$, $p=1,000,000$.

Does anybody know such a dataset or at least where I could get one? I was thinking about natural language processing data but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you generate one writing a small piece of code ? You could include noise in the dependent and independent variables ? About large data sets, may be the Census bureau could provide you one or consumer association too. I suggest you have a look at http://www.census.gov/main/www/access.html

Comment: I did create one myself, however I need some realistic scenario.

Comment: I am afraid it will be difficult to find such a large data set. If I may ask, what is the goal and the purpose ? I am just curious and interested.

Comment: The goal is to test certain dimension reduction techniques. So for example if you just leave away some features this will reduce computational effort but it obviously will mess up the predictions, so we want to test some of these techniques in realistic situations, because simply creating one by myself might tell me the techniques work fine when in reality they dont really work.

Comment: May be you could ask someone to generate the data and you will ignore how they were generated (model, noise, ....).

Comment: Thats an idea. Thanks.